# Python groupby dataframe and sum datetime[ns] returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, sum

I have a dataframe with different id's and corresponding datetime values. I would like to group by the id and sum all the date time values but I run into several problems. Either the groupby returns NaN or it does not allow me to sum datetime[ns].

This is my dataframe:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-13 01:18:11 |
| 2 | 2023-04-10 10:25:03 |
| 1 | 2023-03-31 10:30:44 |
| 3 | 2023-04-04 05:51:33 |
| 4 | 2023-05-01 23:43:34 |
| 5 | 2023-04-19 09:05:39 |
| 2 | 2023-04-12 09:56:50 |
| 6 | 2023-04-28 12:49:23 |
| 3 | 2023-04-17 08:10:34 |

```
data = {'id': [1,2,1,3,4,5,2,6,3], 'date': ['2023-04-13T01:18:11.000000000', '2023-04-10T10:25:03.000000000',
       '2023-03-31T10:30:44.000000000', '2023-04-04T05:51:33.000000000',
       '2023-05-01T23:43:34.000000000', '2023-04-19T09:05:39.000000000',
       '2023-04-12T09:56:50.000000000', '2023-04-28T12:49:23.000000000','2023-04-17T08:10:34.000000000']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.date = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I have tried to groupby the id but it sums to NaN:
`grouped_df = df.groupby("id", as_index=False)["date"].sum()`

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |
| 2 | NaN |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | NaN |
| 5 | NaN |
| 6 | NaN |

Comment: You can sum only numeric values. Why do you need to sum the datetime values?

Comment: What does it mean for you to sum dates? Maybe you want to aggregate dates of each group in a list like `df.groupby("id", as_index=False)["date"].agg(list)`? However you can compute the difference between each date `df.sort_values('date').groupby("id", as_index=False)["date"].diff()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum the difference between datetimes then you need to calculate the difference between them.

```
df.date.diff().sum()
```

In this way, it will calculate the difference between the second and the first, the third and the second... and so on. And then you can sum it.

[Pandas diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Since you wanted to groupby the whole df by id.

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['date'].diff().sum()
```

This will print a single phrase

> Timedelta('2 days 11:03:21')

If you want to use it you need to parse it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! So, what I would like to achieve is the sum of each of the dates but per id so something like this:  | id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 days|
| 2 | 1 day|
| 3 | 5 days|
| 4 | ...|
| 5 | ...|
| 6 | ...|

The format does not have to be ".. days" it can be .dt.days and just an integer but that would be the goal! Thanks so much!